# Plot contour lines on a sphere

Tags: plotting

I have this code to plot contours:

```
ContourPlot[(Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ])^(1/4), {θ, -π/2, π/2}, {ϕ, -π/2, π/2}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

How would I map those contours on a unit sphere (if it is even possible) where `θ` and `ϕ` are the spherical angles for the sphere (`θ` is the inclination calculated from the xy plane and `ϕ` is azimuth calculated from the x-axis)?

In a post here, I saw a different problem and the suggestion was to use [`MeshFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) so I tried:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[ϕ] Cos[θ],Cos[ϕ] Cos[θ],Sin[θ]},
{θ, -π/2, π/2}, {ϕ, -π/2, π/2}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {
ContourPlot[(Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ])^(1/4), {θ, -π/2, π/2}, {ϕ, -π/2, π/2}, 
    AxesLabel -> Automatic]
}]
```

but it spits errors and I do not even know whether this approach is correct.

Answer (score 8):

EDIT: Corrected slot numbers per input from Simon Wood.

Look at the documentation for [`MeshFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html)

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[ϕ] Cos[θ], 
  Cos[ϕ] Cos[θ], 
  Sin[θ]}, {θ, -π/2, π/2}, {ϕ, -π/
   2, π/2}, MeshFunctions -> {(Cos[#4] Cos[#5])^(1/4) &},
 PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Comment: The parameters theta and phi are #4 and #5 in the mesh function.

Answer (score 8):

You could use [`SliceContourPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceContourPlot3D.html):

```
expr = TransformedField["Spherical" -> "Cartesian",
 (Cos[θ - π/2] Cos[ϕ])^(1/4), {r, θ, ϕ} -> {x, y, z}];

SliceContourPlot3D[expr, "CenterSphere", {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

The missing parts of the sphere are where your expression isn't real.

Comment: Note that the OP's phi is not the traditional spherical phi:  phi = 0 is the xy plane for the OP.  At least that's how I read it before.

Comment: @MichaelE2, thanks, I hadn't spotted that.